# Loopback 3: Implement Social auth on an api-only project

Tags: rest, loopbackjs

I'm evaluating loopback 3 for a REST API only server, and I want to allow clients to login using social platforms. Most of the API methods will be restricted with access token and ACL. After investigating, I found that the common architecture for social login is

1. Client side (browser) negotiates a valid social token with provider (lets say Facebook)
2. Client submits the social-token to API server (loopback)
3. Server validates the token with the provider (Facebook), creates local User, and returns access token for the REST API (of course, this must be a resolved server side with one operation called from client)

I already implemented the proposed solution for social auth on loopback (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport), but I couldn't find the way to include the upper architecture on it. Specifically:

1. The `loopback-example-passport` includes server side views and stuff I don't want in my project (and I'm not sure what to remove)
2. I'm not sure on which method call to validate facebook's token, create the User (it not existing) and return client access token.

This is a diagram of the expected architecture:
[image]
(Image credit: https://medium.com/@spyna/how-really-protect-your-rest-api-after-social-login-with-node-js-3617c336ebed)